# Do Colombia and Norway have an extradition treaty?

Tags: treaty, extradition

I had no success googling this and thought it would be better to try here before contacting embassies.

Answer (score 1):

Although an [extradition treaty is required](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/98-958.pdf) between the US and some other requesting nation, that may not be the case with Norway. There is a law pertaining to extradition, the current version being [here](https://lovdata.no/dokument/NL/lov/1975-06-13-39); an English translation of an earlier version (not significantly changed) is [here](http://app.uio.no/ub/ujur/oversatte-lover/data/lov-19750613-039-eng.pdf). That law spells out the general conditions for any extradition, so a specific treaty is not required by Norway. I don't know of a place that lists all of the treaties of Norway.

Comment: Great, I would also like to hear from the Colombian perspective regarding Norwegian citizens.